# not able to add LWC cmp on the app page

Tags: lightning-web-components

try to add this lwc cmp on a page but it is showing an error and not adding to the page.

> Action.prototype.finishAction Error  [Error in $A.getCallback()
> [p.navigatiommixin is not a function] Callback failed:
> serviceComponent://flexipage.editor.aura.component.FlexipageComponentController/ACTION$loadComponentDefinitions]
> new
> Aura.externalLibraries()@https://vml-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/7FPkrq_-upw5gdD4giTZpg/aura_prod.js:354:407
> {anonymous}()@https://vml-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/7FPkrq_-upw5gdD4giTZpg/aura_prod.js:116:1

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getApartment from '@salesforce/apex/appApartmentDetailsClass.getApartment';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { navigatiommixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import getSearchedProperty from '@salesforce/apex/appApartmentDetailsClass.getSearchedProperty';
import { registerListener, unregisterAllListeners} from 'c/pubSub';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class ApartmentSearchResult extends navigatiommixin (LightningElement) {
    @track apartments;
    @track apartmentFound;
    @track showContactDetails = false;
    @track apartOwnerid;
    @track bedFilter;
    @track bathroomfilter;
    @track availableFilter;
    @track budgerfilter;

    @wire(getApartment)
    wiredproperties({data,error}){
        if(data){
            this.apartments= data;
            this.apartmentFound=true;
        }
        else if (error){
            this.ShowToast('Error', error.body.message,'error');
            this.apartmentFound=false;
        }
    }
        ShowToast(title,message,variant){
            const event = new ShowToastEvent({
                title: title,
                message: message,
                variant: variant,
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
        showContact(event){
            this.apartOwnerid= event.target.value;
            this.showContactDetails = true;
        }
        closeDetails(){
            this.showContactDetails = false;
        }
        @wire (CurrentPageReference) pageRef;
        connectedCallback(){
            registerListener("handleBedroomChange", this.handleBedroomChange,this);
        }
        disconnectedCallback(){
            unregisterAllListeners(this);
        }
        handleBedroomChange(bedChange){
            this.bedFilter = bedChange;
            getSearchedProperty({
                bedroom: this.bedFilter,
                bathroom: this.bathroomfilter,
                maxbudget: this.budgerfilter,
                available: this.availableFilter

            })
            .then(result=>{
                this.apartments = result;
            })
            .catch(error=>{
                this.ShowToastEvent('ERROR', error.body.message,'error');
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you try adding it someplace else, It seems there is a issue with the component ?

Comment: Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/363736/edit) your post and at minimum include the JS file content for the LWC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"x is not a function" type errors are the result of typos. In this case, you wrote `navigatiommixin`, which is the typo. You'll need to find and replace that typo with the correct value, most likely `NavigationMixin` (note that JavaScript is case-sensitive, which may also be a contributing factor).